# NetSuite Using SuiteScript how do I get the current logged in user local info, ex. date format?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I need to adjust a date format entered by the user based upon the users "localization" settings. So when the user is entering the form I need to be able to check how they have their date formatting localized. I don't see in the currently logged in user data, is there a way to do this?

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found it. If you use the config module you can load "config.Type.USERPREFERENCES" and get back a record of the "current user preferences". It is a record so record.getValue('DATEFORMAT') will return the date format chosen by the user.

thanks

Comment: On a related note, you can use the `format.format()` and `format.parse()` functions to automatically convert JavaScript date objects to the desired format for the current user.  No need to grab their format setting and convert it manually.  If you're using SS1.0, it's `nlapiStringToDate()` and `nlapiDateToString()`.

Comment: Hi and thanks, it is actually the opposite, I have to take the string the user has input before saving the record and change  the format to US from their Euro. But thanks for the info, always good to know